# Altering WinSCP timestamp, get file(s) from a specified date-named folder

Tags: date, ftp, timestamp, sftp, winscp

I have a directory that has multiple folders that are date-named *YYYYMMDD* and they have text file(s) in them.

I want to be able to get the files from the folder that was named with the date 5 days ago.

The script below gets the current date named folder by using ***%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%***:

> get "/some/random/path/***%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%***/*.txt" "C:\receivables\"

For instance, lets say today is *20180724*. It will get all the text file(s) from the folder named *20180724*; however, I want it to get the text file(s) from the folder named *20180719* which will be 5 days previous. How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WinSCP `%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp) supports relative times. So you can use:

```
get "/some/random/path/%TIMESTAMP-5D#yyyymmdd%/*.txt" "C:\receivables\"
```

---

*This is a relatively new feature, so make sure you have the latest version of WinSCP.*